# DataGridView: How to change cell color depending on data source value

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

If my dataset has the following records

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
A    D    H 
B    E    I
C    F    J
```

I want to highlight the cells where values are either C,E,F. The highlight should happen during assign of datasource to DataGridView. Tried CellValueChanged event, but can't make it achieve what I want to do.

I hope not to go iterate each cell and validate the value.

Doable?

TIA!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Highlight Color for particular cells in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789243/highlight-color-for-particular-cells-in-datagridview)

Answer (score 0):

I've not used `CellFormatting` or `CellPainting` much but I think that, in this case, `CellFormatting` might be the better option. This example worked for me:

```vb
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    Dim cell = DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)

    Select Case TryCast(cell.Value, String)
        Case "C", "E", "F"
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
    End Select
End Sub
```

`CellFormatting` is raised per cell, every time a cell needs formatting. That means that, unlike `CellValueChanged`, it will be raised when the cell is initially created.